# how to import new project in android SDK

Tags: java, android

I downloaded the project from https://github.com/owncloud/News-Android-App. And going to open this project in Android Studio.Using open project and import project from the file menu but the project is not get build it again again hang the  Android Studio.

Comment: yes, in androd sdk

Comment: it should be android Studio I guess?

Comment: have you imported any project before, in android SDK ?

Comment: Please mention the exact errors you are getting otherwise its impossible to know what the problem is?

Comment: No error,but SDK goes hang

Comment: What are your PC  specs?

Comment: which platform you  are using ? android studio or eclipse ?

Comment: I am using android studio

Answer (score 0):

Its clearly documented in the repo readme file

> Download and install:
>
> Open cmd/terminal
>
> Navigate to your workspace
>
> Then type in:
>
> git clone --recursive https://github.com/owncloud/News-Android-App.git
>   for the dev branch:
>
> git clone --recursive https://github.com/owncloud/News-Android-App.git
>   -b dev Run the following script News-Android-App/remove_invalid_languages.sh
>
> Import the Project and start coding!
>
> If you should ever get a Gradle error Configuration with name
>   'default' not found while building, execute following commands in the
>   projects root directory:
>
> `git submodule init
>   git submodule update`

**UPDATE**
I tried to import the project myself and found that it requires multiple API and Build tool versions. after installing all of them It takes a significant amount of time to build. Wait for the Android studio to build the project.

I have recorded my steps with windows recorder. Here they are https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Juf5kLJb5QdjZGQUExNkJZYnc/view?usp=sharing